# Relative clause and participle

Tags: relative-clauses, participles, present-participles

I've never heard the following participial phrase, and it sounds unnatural to me:

Instead of

> "There is no way that you are so tall."

one would write

> "There is no way you being so tall."

I mean that "that" implies a relative clause: is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not grammatical.

It is not true that *that* implies a relative clause. It *can* introduce a relative clause, but here it is a complement clause.

It might look like a relative clause because it appears to qualify the noun *way*, and in anothe context (where *way* is being used literally) it could do so:

> That's the way [that] leads home the quickest.

where it answers the question "which way?"

But in your example sentence, even leaving aside the fact that *no way* is an idiom which cannot be analysed, "that you are so tall" is not in any sense an answer to the question "which way?"

Comment: 'There is no way [that] _something is the case_ ' can be a casual conversational way of expressing surprise by pretended disbelief. 'There is no way you are so tall' sounds like something an adult might say to a child they haven't seen for a while. A modern version of 'My, how you've grown!'

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any source that shows how to identify relativ clauses?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the sources. But I suspect that it is always going to involve some heuristics. I'm pretty sure you could come up with a sentence where the a clause could be either a relative or not, depending on context.